# Change anchor text and icon with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, anchor, toggleclass

I have an anchor tag which hides or shows a div but I've been unable to change it's text and icon.

How do I change the text AND icon tag, as currently it parses the icon tag out as regular text.

Anchor tag:

```
<a class="collapse-info btn"><i class="icon-arrow-up icon-white"></i> Hide Info</a>
```

I need the class to go from "icon-arrow-up icon-white" to "icon-arrow-down icon-white" and back during toggles.

Javascript (jquery)

```
$('.collapse-info').toggle(function() {
$('.server-info').slideUp();
$(this).text('Show Info');
}, function () {
$('.server-info').slideDown();
$(this).text('Hide Info');
});
```

Was trying something like $("#collapse-icon").toggleClass('icon-arrow-down'); but that won't work since the anchor text is overwritten after the initial toggle.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QCDz9/)

```
$('.collapse-info').toggle(function() {
    //$('.server-info').slideUp();
    $(this).find("i").removeClass("icon-arrow-up").addClass("icon-arrow-down");
    this.childNodes[1].nodeValue = "Show Info";
}, function () {
    //$('.server-info').slideDown();
    $(this).find("i").removeClass("icon-arrow-down").addClass("icon-arrow-up");
    this.childNodes[1].nodeValue = "Hide Info";
});
```

Comment: Thanks works great. Was not aware of childnodes but great to know!

Comment: Sorry to bring this question back from the dead but I can't seem to figure out what I changed to my code to cause the button to disappear on load. http://jsfiddle.net/wdD7B/  I've tried to comment out certain parts but I can't pinpoint the reason.

Comment: that's jQuery changed smth ( have no time to go through the changelog ), but if you use 1.8.3 instead of 1.9 it just works - http://jsfiddle.net/wdD7B/1/

Answer (score 0):

first of all, the `<i>` tag is used for italic text and not icons.

now to answer your question, i'm assuming you have some kind of background image assigned to your `<i>` tag that you'd like to change.

why don't you assign the class to the `<a>` tag itself, instead of an element inside the a tag.
then changing the html of the a tag won't cause you a problem.

your js would then look like the following:

```
$('.collapse-info').toggle(function() {
  $('.server-info').slideUp();
  $(this).text('Show Info');
  $(this).addClass('icon-arrow-down').removeClass('icon-arrow-up');
}, function () {
  $('.server-info').slideDown();
  $(this).text('Hide Info');
  $(this).addClass('icon-arrow-up').removeClass('icon-arrow-down');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it seems twitter bootstrap (my framework) decided to use <i> for their icons so not much of a choice there: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons